# Jquery click event not registering on objects scrollbar

Tags: jquery

I'm using a very basic click event:

```
$('body').on('click','.object',click_function);
```

However the click event does not fire if I click on .object's scrollbar (due to the layout this happens frequently).

Is there a way for the click event to bubble past the scrollbar?

Jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/mX9TL/

Comment: are you sure youre clicking the objects scrollbar or the bodys scrollbar?

Comment: provide a jsfiddle which replicates your issue

Comment: definitely clicking the objects scrollbar

Answer (score 0):

instead of 'body' try the below approach

```
$(document).on('click','.object',click_function);
```

let me know if the issue still exist

Comment: No luck unfortunately!